# Adding items from class from one page to another in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this separate screen with 'FoodIcon' class and a list inside of it that is calling it:

**food_icon.dart**

```
class FoodIcon {
  String name;
  IconButton foodIcon;

  FoodIcon(this.name, this.foodIcon);

  List foods = [
    FoodIcon('Beef',
        IconButton(icon: Image.asset('assets/beef.png'), onPressed: null)),
    
  ];
}
```

Now how would I access the List 'foods' from the FoodIcon class from food_icon.dart on another screen (main.dart)? For example if I have a Container with the AlertDialog on another screen:

**main.dart**

```
Widget _buildIcon() {
return AlertDialog(
  title: Text('Add Icon'),
  content: Container(//For example how do I access elements of the list from another page here, for example I would want a 3x3 row of icons from the FoodIcon icons list (name and then the icon itself besides it)),
```

I imported the page where the FoodIcon class is on the page I want it accessed on, but how would I go around getting to the List and the elements inside of it?

Added full code of the page I would need it on:

```
 class FoodList extends StatefulWidget {
 


  @override
  _FoodListState createState() => _FoodListState();
}
class _FoodListState extends State<FoodList> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    DatabaseProvider.db.getFoods().then(
      (foodList) {
        BlocProvider.of<FoodBloc>(context).add(SetFoods(foodList));
      },
    );
   
  }

  Widget _buildIcon() {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Add Icon'),
     
      content: Container(),
      actions: [
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('Cancel'),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
  return Container(
  child: //some button that would show _buildIcon() alert window on tap}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, after some experimentation, I got it to work like this:

**food_icon.dart**

```
class FoodIcon {
  String name;
  IconButton foodIcon;

  FoodIcon(this.name, this.foodIcon);

  static List<FoodIcon> foods() {
    return <FoodIcon>[
      FoodIcon('Beef',
          IconButton(icon: Image.asset('assets/beef.png'), onPressed: null))
    ];
  }
```

**main.dart**

initialized it like this:

```
List<FoodIcon> _foodIcons = FoodIcon.foods();
```

}